# Refactoring a long function in a separate file

Tags: javascript, angular, refactoring

I have an angular application with some search functionality and some radio buttons. And I have a function that becomes 'very' large. So I moved that function into a separate file. But now the radio buttons don't work anymore.

So the component looks like this:

```
export class ExtendedSearchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

//And here I had this function: 

  setSelectedSearchOptions(optionLabel: string) {

    this.filterSelectedSearchOptios; 
    this.selectedOption = optionLabel;
    this.selectedSearch = optionLabel;

    if (optionLabel === 'Registratie') {
       this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.buttonFilterDisabled = false;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.selectedValue = '';
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;
    }

    if (optionLabel === 'Vcheq') {
      this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.isButtonVisible = true;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = true;
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownQrCode = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;

    }

    if (optionLabel === 'Doelen') {
      this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.isButtonVisible = false;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.selectedValue = ',';
      this.selectedValueOptie = ',';
      this.selectedValueProgressie = ',';
      this.showDropdownQrCode = true;
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;

    }
  }

}
```

and the template of the component looks like this:

```
<form class="from-horizontal" #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="filterSection" (ngSubmit)="closeSearch(form)">
  <div class="filter-plus mat-elevation-z8" [ngClass]="{ expanded: searchExpanded }">
    <div class="filter-plus-search-fields">
      <div class="search-types">
        <mat-radio-group>
          <mat-radio-button
            *ngFor="let option of this.filterListData.searchOptions; let i = index"
            [value]="i"
            [checked]="i === 0"
            [(value)]="option"
            (change)="this.filterSelectedSearchOptios.setSelectedSearchOptions(option.label)"
          >
            {{ option.label }}
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </div>
</form>
```

But I moved that function into a separate file, like this:

```
export class filterSelectedSearchOptions{


  showDropdownQrCode = false;
  showDropdownChallenge = false;
  showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
  showDropdownMeasurement = false;
  showDropdownIndicator = false;
  searchExpanded = false;
  submitEnabled = false;
  buttonFilterDisabled: boolean;

  selectedSearch = 'Registratie';
  selectedValue: string;
  selectedValueStatus: string;
  selectedValueOptie: string;
  selectedVcheqOption: string;
  selectedQrcode: string;

  selectedValueProgressie: string;
  startDate: Date;
  selectedSearchOptions = {};
  isButtonVisible = true;
  isButtonFourVisible = false;
  isButtonFiveVisible = false;
  isButtonMeasurements = false;
  showDatePickerOne = true;
  showDatePickerTwo = true;
  showDatePickerThree = true;
  selectedOption: any = 'Registratie';


   setSelectedSearchOptions(optionLabel: string) {
    //this.filterSection.reset();
    this.selectedOption = optionLabel;
    this.selectedSearch = optionLabel;

    if (optionLabel === 'Registratie') {
       this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.buttonFilterDisabled = false;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.selectedValue = '';
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;
    }

    if (optionLabel === 'Vcheq') {
      this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.isButtonVisible = true;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = true;
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownQrCode = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;

    }

    if (optionLabel === 'Doelen') {
      this.showDatePickerOne = true;
      this.showDatePickerTwo = false;
      this.showDatePickerThree = false;
      this.showDropdownMeasurement = false;
      this.isButtonVisible = false;
      this.startDate = undefined;
      this.selectedValue = ',';
      this.selectedValueOptie = ',';
      this.selectedValueProgressie = ',';
      this.showDropdownQrCode = true;
      this.showDropdownChallenge = false;
      this.showDropdownVcheqCode = false;
      this.showDropdownIndicator = false;

    }
}
```

and so I have the component now looks like this:

```
export class ExtendedSearchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {


  public filterListData:FilterListData;

 ngOnInit() {

 this.filterSelectedSearchOptios = new filterSelectedSearchOptions();
}
```

and the template of the component looks now like this:

```
<form class="from-horizontal" #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="filterSection" (ngSubmit)="closeSearch(form)">
  <div class="filter-plus mat-elevation-z8" [ngClass]="{ expanded: searchExpanded }">
    <div class="filter-plus-search-fields">
      <div class="search-types">
        <mat-radio-group>
          <mat-radio-button
            *ngFor="let option of this.filterListData.searchOptions; let i = index"
            [value]="i"
            [checked]="i === 0"
            [(value)]="option"
            (change)="this.filterSelectedSearchOptios.setSelectedSearchOptions(option.label)"
          >
            {{ option.label }}
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </div>
</form>
```

But now the radio buttons don't work anymore.

So my question is. What do I have to fix so that the radio buttons will work again with the new created file: filterSelectedSearchOptions

and also how can I refactor the function: setSelectedSearchOptions?

Thank you

if I do this:

```
export class ExtendedSearchComponent extends  FilterSelectedSearchOptions implements OnInit, OnChanges 

 public filterSelectedSearchOptios: FilterSelectedSearchOptions;


 ngOnInit() {


    this.filterSelectedSearchOptios = new FilterSelectedSearchOptions();

}
```

still the radio buttons dont work. I don't get any errors but if I select a radio button no changes

Answer (score 0):

In your refactored code  `this` refer to the other class and that will not work in your component.So you can use `inheritance` instead So move your code to another file and `extands` your component class something like

```
export class ExtendedSearchComponent extends filterSelectedSearchOptions implements OnInit, OnChanges  {
```

no need to change HTML

Comment: Ah, yes. It works now. Thank you! But is it possible to shorten the function in the seperated file? That was my other question

Comment: But there is still a problem. Because if I change from a radio button to other radio button, sometimes the label of a dropdownlist will not been shown. Only when I click on the dropdownlist then the label will appear of the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

The value of the '*this*' keyword begins to refer to a different object that gets created when you use the 'new filterSelectedSearchOptions();' value. So, better off would be to use the below syntax in the component.ts file:

```
    this.filterSelectedSearchOptios = filterSelectedSearchOptions;
```

(where the RHS reference is gotten by using import from the *seperate* file where you have exported the *filterSelectedSearchOptions* class)

Comment: But what do you mean? if I do that I get errors: Type 'typeof FilterSelectedSearchOptions' is missing the following properties from type 'FilterSelectedSearchOptions': showDropdownQrCode, showDropdownChallenge, showDropdownVcheqCode, showDropdownMeasurement, and 22 more.ts(2740)